# why mongoose validator not validating field type?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to validate mongoose schema, but i could not able to understand one thing which is a validation of type. I am passing number type to a string field and expecting it to fail in validation but it passes. how that is happening, can anyone please explain the logic behind this?

sample.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async function validateSample(sample) {
  try {
    await sample.validate();
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

async function execMethod(){
  var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    phone: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 4,
      validate: {
        validator: function(v) {
          return /^\d+$/.test(v);
        },
        message: `not a valid phone number!`
      },
      required: [true, 'User phone number required']
    }
  });
  
  var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
  var validUser = new User({phone: '1234'});
  var invalidUser = new User({phone: 1235});
  const result = await validateSample(validUser);
  const result1 = await validateSample(invalidUser);
  console.log(result);  // true
  console.log(result1)  // expected false as number type is assigned to phone. But returns true, why?
}

execMethod()
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually [a feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#cast-errors) of Mongoose validation.

> Before running validators, Mongoose attempts to coerce values to the
>   correct type. This process is called casting the document. If casting fails for a given path, the error.errors object will contain a `CastError` object.
>
> Casting runs before validation, and validation does not run if casting fails.

In this case, a number `1235` gets cast to a string `'1235'`, which passed the validation just fine.

Now, there's [a FR open](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8407) for providing Mongoose with ability to override cast logic (either disable it completely or customize), but it's Open, not implemented.

Another way is altering casting type-wide ([allowed since 5.4](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7256/files#diff-96513845e54cb391b3da24f69d2d0ec8)), like this:

```
mongoose.Schema.Types.String.cast(false); // prevents all casts to string
```

... but it might be cumbersome, as the same rule's applied to all the objects.

Comment: how can i overcome this issue? do i need any change in schema to achieve this?

Comment: Depends on what you want here. Compile-time type checks can be done through static typing systems - TypeScript is one obvious choice, but there's more (JSDoc, Flow, etc. - you name it). For run-time checks you can use validator that actually allows preventing the casts (like Joi, for example).

Comment: @muthu There's another approach implemented right here - https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/7256 - overriding casts for mongoose types. It's cumbersome (why do I want to override casts based on Types, not on Schema?), but it might help in your particular case.

Comment: @muthy Updated m̶y̶ ̶j̶o̶u̶r̶n̶a̶l̶   the answer.